# Exam: only show a total point value per question, adding parts

Tags: exam

Is there an easy way to display only the points-per-question in an exam, automatically adding the points from the parts and printing the total next to the question?  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question This is a question with parts.
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] This
    \part[2] That
    \part[3] The Other
  \end{parts}
  \question[3] Another question!
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The output should display `1. (6 points) ...` for question 1 and **each part will have the points suppressed (i.e. points won't be printed there)**.  This seems like it should be possible (grade tables exist after all), but I can't seem to figure it out and there isn't anything like this in the documentation on the CTAN...  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier solution in the manual.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qpoints}{\@ifundefined{pointsofq@\roman{question}}{}%
  {(\csname pointsofq@\roman{question}\endcsname ~points)~}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question\qpoints This is a question with parts.
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] This
    \part[2] That
    \part[3] The Other
  \end{parts}
  \question[3] Another question!
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

This version removes normal point listings.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qpoints}{\@ifundefined{pointsofq@\roman{question}}{}%
  {(\csname pointsofq@\roman{question}\endcsname ~points)~}}
\makeatother
\pointformat{\hspace{-5pt}} % prevents other points from being printed

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question\qpoints This is a question with parts.
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] This
    \part[2] That
    \part[3] The Other
  \end{parts}
  \question[3]\qpoints Another question!
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is still a problem with question 2 (after using `\pointformat{}`); I think I can fix this using another conditional within `\qpoints` and supplying an argument specifying an override of points.

Comment: BTW, if you look in the aux file you will find the names of many similar macros.

Answer (score 0):

Based on John's answer: use `\pointsdroppedatright` to suppress part points. Use `\totalpoints` for non-part questions.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qpoints}{\@ifundefined{pointsofq@\roman{question}}{}%
  {(\csname pointsofq@\roman{question}\endcsname ~points)~}}
\makeatother

\pointsdroppedatright

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question\qpoints This is a question with parts.
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] This
    \part[2] That
    \part[3] The Other
  \end{parts}
  \question[3] (\totalpoints~points)~Another question!
  \question[4] (\totalpoints~points)~Another question!
  \question[5] (\totalpoints~points)~Another question!
  \question[6] (\totalpoints~points)~Another question!
  \question[7] (\totalpoints~points)~Another question!
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```